# Improving Existing MySQL LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql

My query runs a bit slow (slower than I would like). I know the general basics of MySQL but not enough to optimize queries. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT a.index, a.date, b.description, a.type, a.place, a.value, b.space,a.val2
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.index = b.index
WHERE a.date >= ? and a.date < ?
AND a.type = 100;
```

I have an index on A's index and type as well as B's index. I know this query could be faster, so I was wondering if anyone might know of some proper optimization.

Thanks

Comment: use EXPLAIN to find out where you need an index

Comment: create a index on date and type

Comment: index on index fields is good, but where runs on a.date and a.type fields, you might want to add them to the index.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, everyone.